# How to make different img appear when hovering over a different li

Tags: html, css, background, hover

im trying to make the background of a parent div change when hovering over a li in its child.. i did that but now i want to display a different img when hovering over a different li inside the same child div... i cant seem to do that and cant find anyone else having the same problem.. and if it needs JavaScript also i dont mind

i tried to specify the li but it doesnt work

heres the css code

```
#mainpage{  
    pointer-events: none;
}

#listman {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

#mainpage:hover {
    background: url("bg1.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 500x; 
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

and heres the html part

```
div id="mainpage">
        
        
<div id="listman">
        <ul class="bigger">
        <li id="listman1" href="#"> <a> 1 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman2" href="#"> <a> 2 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman3" href="#"> <a> 3 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman4" href="#"> <a> 4 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman5" href="#"> <a> 5 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman6" href="#"> <a> 6 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman7" href="#"> <a> 7 </a> </li>
        <li id="listman8" href="#"> <a> 8 </a> </li>
    
</ul>
    
    </div>
        </div>
        
</div>
```

i want to make a different img to appear when hovering over (listman2) can anyone help me?

Comment: Please first of all put your code through a validator and correct it - at the moment you have div elements as direct children of a ul which is not allowed.

Comment: And you are also setting a background-color as a url which is also not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS syntax:

```
div#listman > ul.bigger > div#listman2 > li {
   background-image: url("bg1.png");
}
div#listman > ul.bigger > div#listman2 > li:hover + div#listman > ul.bigger > div#listman2 > li {
   background-image: url("bg2.png");
}
```

I'm not sure it will work though

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the li elements do not have their own position and you can make mainpage be the closest positioned element to them then you can put the image on an absolutely positioned pseudo element on each li when it is hovered.

This snippet uses a CSS variable to set the background image for each li element.

```css
#mainpage {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#listman {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

ul.bigger {
  position: relative;
}

li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--bg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#listman1 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
}

#listman2 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/768);
}

#listman3 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1024/768);
}

#listman4 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1024/768);
}

#listman5 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1020/1024/768);
}

#listman6 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1022/1024/768);
}

#listman7 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1023/1024/768);
}

#listman8 {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1024/1024/768);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainpage">


  <div id="listman">
    <ul class="bigger">
      <li id="listman1" href="#"> <a> 1 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman2" href="#"> <a> 2 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman3" href="#"> <a> 3 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman4" href="#"> <a> 4 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman5" href="#"> <a> 5 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman6" href="#"> <a> 6 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman7" href="#"> <a> 7 </a> </li>
      <li id="listman8" href="#"> <a> 8 </a> </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```